# Setting up ActiveJDBC for an Eclipse project that does not use Maven

Tags: eclipse, activejdbc

I read a few things about activejdbc and I liked it. I tried adding it to an Eclipse project that I already have and realised that most of the references on how to add it to projects use Maven. I am not using Maven for my project and I am not ready to use Maven since it doesn't exactly suit what I am trying to do. Could someone please tell me how else (step by step guide) I could get it running on my project.

I am writing a Swing application using MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  look at this Ant example: https://github.com/javalite/ant-example
If you are not using Ant, you can look at the standalone example here: 
https://github.com/javalite/standalone-example. It does not use anything at all.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. BTW The jar versions specified in the .bat files (1.4.1)  does not correspond to the actual jar files in the lib folder (1.4.6)

Comment: if this is a new project, you might want to check out this: http://javalite.io/activeweb. More productive than Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gradle, you can create a task like this:

```
task instrument(dependsOn: 'build', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.javalite.instrumentation.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath += project(':any-other-project-paths-you-want-to-include').sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    jvmArgs '-DoutputDirectory=/Users/ned_stark/voldemort/whitewalkers/legolas/root-dir/build/classes/main/'
}
```

The activejdbc-graddle github example didn't work for me, so I had to do this instead.

Comment: Can you please provide step by step details on how you are doing it? I have a spring boot app with gradle as well.